# Accessing real-time firebase database in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am currently working on a project where we have to access the real-time firebase database data in Android Studio. The data stored in the real-time d[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rzycu.jpg)atabase is in this Format.

How do we access this data in Android Studio Continuously?

Comment: I think you should refer [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write) document before asking the question.

Answer (score 0):

For Continuously observe data firebase is refer to use **addValueEventListener()**

```
    ValueEventListener postListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        // Get Post object and use the values to update the UI
        Post post = dataSnapshot.getValue(Post.class);
        // ..
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        // Getting Post failed, log a message
        Log.w(TAG, "loadPost:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
    }
};
mPostReference.addValueEventListener(postListener);
```

[Documentation Reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#java_4) also There are many video tutorial available on youtube